# how get django current user's name both in shell and in request

Tags: python, django, shell, authentication

I have to update a "modified by" field in models with current user's name.
It's very easy to get username in views with request like this:

> request.user.username

However, when an model's instance is modified using shell (I have scripts to batch update and process entries) there's no request.

What would be a good way to get current user's name both from request (if any) and from shell process?

### Updates based on comments:

#### Custom save, assuming one shell user

Yes, I am using a custom save() method.
It looks like:

- an abstract model class with "general" fields like "modified by" and with a method to update the field; as of the moment it looks like `modified_by = "unknown user"`;
- a real model class takes it as a mixin;
- and many views and scripts work with the model.

So, I know how to manually assign a value to the field.
The problem is to how to know if a particular transaction was done with or without a request, and if without request (shell), then which admin/user done it.

What I tried:

1. Passing request as a required parameter from any view to the abstract models, method: it did not work (at least, I do not know how to safely code a required parameter to and abstract model's method as opposed to a plain function in a view); also, I do not know how to pass request when calling the same method from shell.
2. In shell, I easily got User.objects.all() and tried to check: if user is authenticated, then use his/her username, else assume it's a shell user and manually assign "shell user" value to "modified by".

To my surprise, any returned user is authenticated in shell:

```
>>> users = User.objects.all()
>>> users
[<User: teddy>, <User: alexander>]
>>> users[0].is_authenticated()
True
>>> users[1].is_authenticated()
True
>>>
```

So, this easy scenario failed to me...

#### When custom save() is not enough

Further thought:

1. Batch model updates triggered in admin app do not use `save()`, so any custom logic here will not work...
2. Updating with a Celery task: did not check it yet.
3. More than one shell user: will have to use a plain old user input to ask for the name and pass to the script?

Any idea to help?

## This is how I solved it:

An abstract-class model with a parameter (who) to be manually assigned when saving a model.

```
class ModifiedAwareModel(models.Model):
"""
ABC to keep track of when and by whom a model was created and updated.
"""
created_on = models.DateTimeField(_('created on'), blank=True, editable=False)
created_by = models.CharField(_('created by'), max_length=100, blank=True, editable=False)
modified_on = models.DateTimeField(_('modified on'), blank=True, editable=False)
modified_by = models.CharField(_('modified by'), max_length=100, blank=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def save(self, who="Django", *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.pk:
        self.created_on = timezone.now()
        self.created_by = who
        self.modified_on = timezone.now()
        self.modified_by = who
    else:
        self.modified_on = timezone.now()
        self.modified_by = who
    return super(ModifiedAwareModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Maybe write a custom `save()` function for the model? Why can't you just change the value of the `modified by` field when saving the model from the shell?

Comment: Who is _current user_ in the shell?

Comment: The OS user that runs the shell command is a completely separate concept from the Django `User`.

Comment: There is no "current user" in that case.

Comment: There is technically no user for the shell.

Comment: All the above are right on, you can probably designate a user that carries out this batch processing of yours and you can set modified by to that user

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar like the Community user on SO?

Comment: @techydesigner Yes probably on those line, see there might be a user something like an administrator or something like that and it can be used.

Comment: What about manually updating the `modified by` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Django `shell`, there is no current `User`. A method of working around this would be get the person who is using the shell to assign a `User` to the `modified by` field manually. This `User` would probably be dedicated for shell operations, but it doesn't have to be that way. Another option could be to write a custom `save()` function for the model if you will only be changing it through the shell.

Comment: Manually designating a user seems a clear solution rather than custom save as there might be scenarios where it isnt needed and is just an overhead

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar It is only a suggestion - the OP can decide on what path they would take

Comment: I completely understand that and it was my bad to reply on the comment as well as answer. Apologies.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar It's all good - I am yet to write a django application that needs a custom `save()` function. One day.....

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom save() method, and it looks like:

Comment: @AlexV has your question been answered above or do you require more clarification?

Comment: The above comment was saved by mistake. I updated the question with more details, it has not been answered yet. Please, take a look at my details.